# A duality formula

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-algebras

As we know, in the category of Banach space, we have that  $\ell^1=c_0^*$. Indeed, for any  $(x_n)\in \ell^1$

$$\|(x_n)\|_{\ell^1}=\sum |x_n|=\sup \{|\sum_1^{\infty } t_nx_n| : (t_n)\in B\}$$
where $B$ is the unit ball of $c_0$. It means

$$\|(x_n)\|_{\ell^1}<\infty ~\Longleftrightarrow ~\sum |x_n|<\infty$$

It is supposed to extend this fact for operators:

Let $H$ be a  Hilbert space and $\{x_n\}$ be a sequence of operators in $B(H)$. 
Let us put

$$\|(x_n)\|^{op}_{\ell}:=\sup \{\|\sum_1^{\infty } t_nx_n\| : (t_n)\in B\}$$

Q. What is yor suggestion to complete the following:
 $$\|(x_n)\|^{op}_{\ell}<\infty \Longleftrightarrow  ~~?$$

Comment: $B$ is now the unit ball of $B(H)$?

Comment: Some simple comments you probably already know: In a finite dimensional space it is equivalent to $\sum_n\|x_n\|$ converging, in an infinite dimensional space you have:
$$\sum_n\|x_n\|<\infty\implies \|(x_n)\|_\ell^{op}<\infty\implies \sum_n x_n \text{ convergent in strong operator topology}$$
but neither implication can be turned around. Further, it is a different criterium if you use $x_n t_n$ instead of $t_n x_n$ or $t_n x_n t_n^*$ or $t_n x_n s_n$.

Comment: Thanks for your pay attention. I should mention that $B$ is still the unit  ball of $c_0$.